# reading bool value using viper in Go

Tags: go, viper-go, golang-migrate

I'm using viper to manage the configurations and environment variables for a Go app .
all of values are coming correct from the json config file expect the bool values are always coming false even it have a true value within the json file

```
{
  "database" : {
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port": "3306"
  },
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": ":3000",
  "production": true,
  "cache": true
}
```

the configuration package

```
package config

import (
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "html/template"
    "log"
)

type ViperConfig struct {
    Database struct {
        Host string "json:'host'"
        Port string "json:'port'"
    } "json:'database'"
    Host          string "json:'host'"
    Port          string "json:'port'"
    ProductionMod bool   "json:'production'"
    UseCache      bool   "json:'cache'"
    TemplaCache   map[string]*template.Template
}

func LoadConfig(path string) (viperconfig ViperConfig, err error) {
    viper.AddConfigPath(path)
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("json")
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
    err = viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Can't load config file")
    }
    err = viper.Unmarshal(&viperconfig)
    return
}
```

all of this are working file when i tried to access any string but when tried to access the bool variables it always give false

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2"
    "github.com/fouad82/news-api/cmd/config"
    "github.com/fouad82/news-api/cmd/routes"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ViperConfig, err := config.LoadConfig("../")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Can't read viper configurations", err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error Parsing template", err)
    }
    session := scs.New()
    session.Lifetime = 24 * time.Hour
    session.Cookie.Persist = true
    session.Cookie.SameSite = http.SameSiteLaxMode
    session.Cookie.Secure = ViperConfig.ProductionMod
    routes.Routes()
    // the values never gives the actuall value it always gives false
    log.Fatal(ViperConfig.UseCache, ViperConfig.ProductionMod)
    http.ListenAndServe(ViperConfig.Port, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First the json tags are written wrong.

I think `viper` doesn't use `json` tags. It uses the `mapstructure` tags.
The other variables are working because the name of the variable is the same mapped on the json tags. (check this https://github.com/spf13/viper#unmarshaling)

2 solutions:

First: change the variables name

```
type ViperConfig struct {
    Database struct {
        Host string `json:"host"`
        Port string `json:"port"`
    } `json:"database"`
    Host          string `json:"host"`
    Port          string `json:"port"`
    Production bool   `json:"production"`
    Cache      bool   `json:"cache"`
    TemplaCache   map[string]*template.Template
}
```

Or use mapstructure tags

```
type ViperConfig struct {
    Database struct {
        Host string `json:"host"`
        Port string `json:"port"`
    } `json:"database"`
    Host          string `json:"host"`
    Port          string `json:"port"`
    ProductionMod bool   `json:"production" mapstructure:"production"`
    UseCache      bool   `json:"cache" mapstructure:"cache"`
    TemplaCache   map[string]*template.Template
}
```

Comment: it uses json tags
from viper documentation 
reading from JSON, TOML, YAML, HCL, envfile and Java properties config files

Comment: No... read troubleshooting https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unmarshaling-doesnt-work

Comment: "The most common reason for this issue is improper use of struct tags (eg. yaml or json). Viper uses github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure under the hood for unmarshaling values which uses mapstructure tags by default. Please refer to the library's documentation for using other struct tags. "